# Clear textbox and radio buttons onclick with Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, radio-button, textfield

```
<input id="firstLocation" type="radio" />
<label for="firstLocation">text</label>

<input id="secondLocation" type="radio" />
<label for="secondLocation">text</label>

<input class="cityName" id="locationName" type="text"  value="" />
```

So basically, this is my html. What I want to do now, is to use JavaScript, not jQuery, to clear the text input field (if something had previously been entered) whenever the radio buttons are clicked and to uncheck the radio buttons whenever someone clicks onto the text field. I quickly found a jQuery solution, but got the task to use JavaScript instead. As I'm not having very much experience with JS, I can't wrap my head around it to get it to work.

Any thoughts?
Would appreciate very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) in order to find the elemnts and [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach the event handlers:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#firstLocation, #secondLocation').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
    ele.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        document.querySelector('#locationName').value = '';
    });
});
document.querySelector('#locationName').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    document.querySelectorAll('#firstLocation, #secondLocation').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
       ele.checked=false;
    });
})
```

```html
<input id="firstLocation" type="radio" />
<label for="firstLocation">text</label>

<input id="secondLocation" type="radio" />
<label for="secondLocation">text</label>

<input class="cityName" id="locationName" type="text"  value="" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks much simpler than all my tries!